# Bing Map Geolocation Pointing difference in browser

Tags: bing-maps

I am using

> Bing Map

in my website. If I open in

> Microsoft Edge, positioning of Geo Location

is accurate and the

> same coordinates shall be pointed wrong

if open the site

> in Chromium or Chrome.

Why?

Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

Bing Maps simply uses the Geolocation API that is in the browser. Each browser is responsible for this. As such, some browsers are less accurate than others.